# How do I create a random point on the surface of a cube?

Tags: graphics3d, random-process

How do I create a random point on the surface of a cube? I mean on one of its six faces at random.

Comment: `ListPointPlot3D[RandomSample /@ Transpose[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 1000}]~Join~{RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 1000]}], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ReplacePart[Table[RandomReal[], 3], 
 RandomChoice[Range[3]] -> RandomInteger[{0, 1}]]
```

If you want points on the surface of a $d$-dimensional unit hypercube:

```
d = 5;
ReplacePart[Table[RandomReal[], d], 
RandomChoice[Range[d]] -> RandomInteger[{0, 1}]]
```

Comment: That's a very clever approach!

Comment: I don't know about *faster*. Compared to `RandomPoint[R, 1000]`, how long does your method take to generate 1000 random points?

Comment: @David G. Stork. That depends. If you count in the timing for discretizing the region: Yes, this takes a lot if time. But you have to do that only once.

Comment: You used `Table[RandomPoint[R], 10^6]` instead of `RandomPoint[R, 10^6]`. The latter is about 3 orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Ah... you are correct.  I'll remove my timing claims.

Comment: I believe that at higher dimensions, vectorizing your approach would be faster than using RandomPoint.

Comment: How do I generalize this approach to a non unit cube?

Answer (score 5):

We simply need a `MeshRegion` that represents the *boundary* of the unit cube. Then we apply `RandomPoint` to it. The following shows one of probably many ways to do it.

```
R = DiscretizeRegion@RegionBoundary[Cuboid[]];
RandomPoint[R]
```

Comment: Sorry, not into regions lately, will `RegionBoundary` be ok too?`RandomPoint[DiscretizeRegion@RegionBoundary@Cuboid[], 500]`

Comment: @Kuba Ah right! I tried all combinations of `Mesh` and `Boundary` but forget about `RegionBoundary`! Thank's for the hint.

Comment: Is it possible to find the coordinates of the point?

Comment: `DiscretizeRegion` should really be redundant on this. Consider `RandomPoint@RegionBoundary@Ball[]`. Once again, for some reason it's necessary.

Comment: @kirma That's because `RegionBoundary@Ball[]` reduces to `Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]` and this one has its own branch in `RandomPoint`.  But there isn't such an implementation for `Polygon`s which are not simplices and that's actually for a good reason: These polygons can be nonplanar and it is not trivial to tell what their area should be.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher But cuboid sides are definitely not nonplanar...

Comment: @kirma Yes. What I meant" `RegionBoundary@Cuboid[]` returns a list of quadrilaterals wrapped in `Polygon`. Mathematica would have to run planarity checks when calling `RandomPoint`. While this would be possible, I can understand that it would not be worthwhile to implement that, in particular since there is already an implementation for simplicial `MeshRegion`s. And an automatica conversion would have also its pitfalls. But I agree that I was also puzzled first when I realized that `RandomPoint@RegionBoundary@Cuboid[]` does not evaluate.

Comment: I believe the need for DiscretizeRegion is a bug, and should be reported. It used to work in 11.1. Also, it works in higher dimensions, e.g., `RandomPoint @ RegionBoundary @ Cuboid[{0,0,0,0}, {1,1,1,1}]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Okay. I've just sent a report.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to build it from scratch in case someone finds that interesting:

```
coords = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};
pts = {{4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {2, 3, 7, 6}, {3, 4, 8, 7}, {4, 1, 5, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
polygons = Flatten@Normal@GraphicsComplex[coords, Polygon[pts]];
reg = RegionUnion[DiscretizeRegion /@ polygons];
RandomPoint[reg]
```

I grabbed the coordinates from the documentation for `Hexahedron`.

Comment: Is it possible to find the coordinates of the point?

Comment: @mattiav27 What do you mean? `RandomPoint` returns coordinates.

Comment: I didn't know it thanks!